# Azure : New Landing Zone - naming standards

Tags: azure

Currently, I am working on establishing enterprise-scale landing zones for Cloud Adoption Framework in Azure.

> As part of the activity, I need to define the naming standards across resource groups, environments, physical location, products/types, applications, clients.

I understand that this is more a personal/organizational decision, but I'd like some examples before I can begin working on it. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are deploying a hybrid environment I could imagine that you might have some organizational requirement to follow.

If it is cloud-only, then this is a good starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/resource-naming

The article has a good list of examples

Maybe equally if not more important is imho the tagging scheme: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/resource-tagging